# Error CS0012: The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0

Tags: msbuild, tfsbuild, .net-standard, .net-standard-2.0

I have recently added a package reference to  **Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs**. This is an **ASP.NET Web API** project that implements all our services.

The TFS build however is failing with the following errors.

[image]

[image]

I have added a reference to **netstandard 2.03** but I still get the error.

I am using Visual Studio 2017 15.9.4. I have installed the latest SDKs and build tools on the build server.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to find the answer to this problem [here](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/542). In short, I added the following line to the .csproj

```
<Reference Include="netstandard" />
```